# Material-ui ButtonBase showing grey background instead of image

Tags: reactjs, button, material-ui

I'm new to React and I'm currently working on a project to learn more about it. I'm having some problems with ButtonBase though. When I'm trying to show an image it is showing me a grey background on the button. It is compiling with no errors. i'm guessing that there is something wrong with the way the image is imported. I have tried different methods to import it but none of them worked.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
import TableBody from '@material-ui/core/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableContainer from '@material-ui/core/TableContainer';
import TableHead from '@material-ui/core/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import DeleteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Delete';
import EditIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Edit';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import AddIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Add';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import ButtonBase from '@material-ui/core/ButtonBase';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const images = [
  {
    url: '../images/image1.jpeg',
    title: 'Breakfast',
    width: '40%',
  },
];

const useStyles = theme => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    minWidth: 300,
    width: '100%',
  },
  image: {
    position: 'relative',
    height: 200,
    [theme.breakpoints.down('xs')]: {
      width: '100% !important', // Overrides inline-style
      height: 100,
    },
    '&:hover, &$focusVisible': {
      zIndex: 1,
      '& $imageBackdrop': {
        opacity: 0.15,
      },
      '& $imageMarked': {
        opacity: 0,
      },
      '& $imageTitle': {
        border: '4px solid currentColor',
      },
    },
  },
  focusVisible: {},
  imageButton: {
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    color: theme.palette.common.white,
  },
  imageSrc: {
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    backgroundSize: 'cover',
    backgroundPosition: 'center 40%',
  },
  imageBackdrop: {
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.common.black,
    opacity: 0.4,
    transition: theme.transitions.create('opacity'),
  },
  imageTitle: {
    position: 'relative',
    padding: `${theme.spacing(2)}px ${theme.spacing(4)}px ${theme.spacing(1) + 6}px`,
  },
  imageMarked: {
    height: 3,
    width: 18,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.common.white,
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: -2,
    left: 'calc(50% - 9px)',
    transition: theme.transitions.create('opacity'),
  },
});

/* This view is the one that is seen when one wants to edit a question */

class EditQuestion extends React.Component {
  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);
  }
  render(){
    const {classes} = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="App">
      <h1>Redigera fråga</h1>

      {images.map((image) => (
        <ButtonBase
          focusRipple
          key={image.title}
          className={classes.image}
          focusVisibleClassName={classes.focusVisible}
          style={{
            width: image.width,
          }}
        >
          <span
            className={classes.imageSrc}
            style={{
              backgroundImage: `url(${image.url})`,
            }}
          />
          <span className={classes.imageBackdrop} />
          <span className={classes.imageButton}>
            <Typography
              component="span"
              variant="subtitle1"
              color="inherit"
              className={classes.imageTitle}
            >
              {image.title}
              <span className={classes.imageMarked} />
            </Typography>
          </span>
        </ButtonBase>
      ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(useStyles)(EditQuestion);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It would be easier to understand your issue if you can share a code sandbox for your issue.You can create here in minutes - https://codesandbox.io/?from-app=1

Comment: @VarunGoel Yes, you are right. Here is a code sandbox of the code above https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-cache-f3kgh?file=/src/App.js

Comment: You should change `url(${image.url})` to `url(${images[0].url})` at least

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the image file so that it gets bundled by webpack.Here is the output -

[image]

Working sandbox here - https://codesandbox.io/s/little-cookies-y6urk?file=/src/App.js

You can read more about

> Adding Images, Fonts, and Files

from here  https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/

Comment: That worked! I'm going to check out the link you posted. Thank you!